# In every local ring exist nonzero nilpotent ideals?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals, nilpotence

I read that every local ring is clean so **there exist clean rings with nonzero nilpotent ideals**, i know that a local ring has a unique maximal ideal, but i don't know why do they say this implication.

thank you.

Comment: In a local ring $R=R^\times\cup m$ where $m$ is the unique maximal ideal, $a$ or $a+1$ is a unit, thus it is clean. $k[x]/(x^2)$ is a local ring. $k[x]/(x^2-x)$ is clean but non local (its non-units are $rx,r-rx$ so one of $a,a-1,a-x,a-(1-x)$ is a unit )

Answer (score 0):

> In every local ring exist nonzero nilpotent ideals?

Ridiculous of course, since there are lots of local integral domains.

> every local ring is clean so there exist clean rings with nonzero nilpotent ideals, i know that a local ring has a unique maximal ideal, but i don't know why do they say this implication.

Because it is easy to produce local rings with nilpotent ideals, witnessing this statement.  $\mathbb Z/ 4\mathbb Z$ is local with a nilpotent maximal ideal. Thus it is local, clean, and has such an ideal.

—-

Based on the above, it sounds like you misunderstood the strategy of quantification. The claim only asserted “$\exists$ clean ring with nonzero nilpotent ideal” but you interpreted its solution as “$\forall$ local ring, local ring has nonzero nilpotent ideal, hence $\exists$ a clean ring like that.”  Really it is already sufficient that  “$\exists$ local ring such that it has nonzero nilpotent ideal, hence $\exists$ a clean ring like that.”